# CodeIgniter form validation rules for checkbox

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've a form with checkbox for accepting TOS. The problem is I need to add custom error for this checkbox,

```
    <form>

    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Name" /><?php echo form_error('fname') ?>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" /><?php echo form_error('email') ?>
    <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password" /><?php echo form_error('password') ?>

    <input type="checkbox" name="accept_terms" value="yes" /> Accept TOS<br>
    <?php echo form_error('accept_terms') ?>

    </form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 

 $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname','First Name','trim|required|xss_clean');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','trim|required|xss_clean|valid_email');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required|xss_clean');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('accept_terms','TOS','trim|required|xss_clean'); // Need to add custom error message 

if ( $this->form_validation->run() === TRUE ) {

}else{

}
?>
```

When the user does not select TOS, Then I have to say

> Please read and accept our terms and conditions.

Note: I've added `form_error` function to display individual errors

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo here, but you wrote "accept_tearms" instead of "accept_terms" in your rules

Comment: ahh. my mistake.. It's not typo, I've updated my question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I will do something like this,

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE ) {
   if(!$this->input->post('accept_terms')){
      echo "Please read and accept our terms and conditions.";
      // Redirect
   }
}
else{

}
```

And for custom message you can call a custom validate function like,

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('accept_terms', '...', 'callback_accept_terms');
```

And then set up this method in the controller:

```
function accept_terms() {
    if (isset($_POST['accept_terms'])) return true;
    $this->form_validation->set_message('accept_terms', 'Please read and accept our terms and conditions.');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But Is there any easy solution to using with form_error function.

Comment: @Mifas - another method added :)

Comment: I didn't realize we can use $_POST variable with in our callback function. Thanks. Its working perfectly

Comment: You may want to rename the `accept_terms()` function `_accept_terms()` and `callback_accept_terms` to `callback__accept_terms`, other wise the accept_terms method will be accessible via the browser @ http://sample.com/controler/accept_terms any function that starts with a underscore is hidden from public access.

Answer (score 0):

you can put the value=1 and check with codeigniter like this:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="accept_terms" value="1" /> Accept TOS<br>
$this->form_validation->set_rules('accept_terms','TOS','trim|required|xss_clean|greater_than[0]');
```

]