# Form validation, call function not working in codeigniter 3.0.3

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

This is a small rule for checking select option, but it doesn't work

```
array(
    'field'=>'student_class',
    'label'=>'Student Class',
    array(
        'required',
        array(
            'student_class_callable',
            function($str)
            {
                if($str == 0)
                {
                    return FALSE;
                }
                return TRUE;
            },
        ),
    ),
    'errors' => array(
         'required' => 'Please Select Student Class',
    ),
),
```

other field are being verified by the form validation, but not one

select option look like this

```
<select name="student_class">
    <option value="0">Please Select Class</option>
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter form validation rules for checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854232/codeigniter-form-validation-rules-for-checkbox)

Comment: is the callback function getting called??

Answer (score 0):

I think your callback is not getting called, try this

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('student_class','Student Class','required|callback_check_default');
$this->form_validation->set_message('check_default', 'Please Select Student Class');

function check_default($str){
    $str == 0 ? return false : return true ;

}
```